# Can I ignore a Git repository's mailmap?

Tags: git, mailmap

I have a custom mailmap file for a Git repository which I configure using a per-repository [`mailmap.file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mailmapfile) setting. However, if there's a mailmap file in the root of the repository it seems to interfere with my mappings. Is there any way I can ignore that file?

Comment: As there is inference between two files, why does the approach with gitignore not work? Perhaps you can create a small reproducible example?

Comment: `.gitignore` only works for _untracked_ files, while `.mailmap` is part of the repo.

Comment: And you don't want to remove the file from tracking it seems?

Comment: No, it's not my private repository :) It just used to have no `.mailmap` file.

Comment: But then you could remove it from tracking?